# Hide specific text on load but use same text to identify element for click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide links containing "NOSP" when clicking a No Spoiler button, but also hide that "NOSP" text by default.

Using jQuery this is what I've tried so far:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
$("a:contains('NOSP')").hide();
});

$("a:contains('NOSP')").each(function(){
$(this).text($(this).text().replace('NOSP',''))
});
```

```css
a { display: table; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Hide spoilers</button>

<a href="#">Full match</a>
<a href="#">All goals NOSP</a>
<a href="#">Highlights</a>
<a href="#">Highlights</a>
<a href="#">Highlights NOSP</a>
```

(also a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e1qx58bm/))

Comment: Do you have control over the HTML?

Comment: Yes. it's a wiki (MediaWiki software) and users will be asked to label video links containing spoilers with "NOSP" (or just an asterisk). Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstood your question - it's user-generated content and for simplicity, users should only have to add NOSP or * to the link text to indicate that the link contains spoilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pre-process all this with $(document).ready and add a className to each `NOSP` link to reference it later, and at the same time remove that string from the link text. Note: just in case there is some word out there with NOSP in it, I broke the text into an array and used `array.includes(targ)` to find it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("a").each(function() {
        let t = $(this).text().split(" ")
        if (t.includes('*')) {
          t.splice(t.indexOf('*'), 1)
          $(this).addClass('nosp').text(t.join(" "))
        }
      })
      $("button").click(function() {
        $("a.nosp").hide();
      });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Hide spoilers</button>

<a href="#">Full match</a>
<a href="#">All goals *</a>
<a href="#">Highlights</a>
<a href="#">Highlights</a>
<a href="#">Highlights *</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great. I used NOSP for clarity, the actual string is just an asterisk (*) not used elsewhere - can the code be simplified?

Comment: I simplified it a little. It's already pretty compact

Comment: Thanks! addClass before removing the asterisk was the solution.

    $("a").each(function() {
    $("a:contains('*')").addClass('nospoilers').text($(this).text().replace('*',''));
    });
      
    $("button").click(function() {
    $(".nospoilers").hide();
    });

Comment: This rather: 
$("a:contains('*')").each(function() {
 $(this).addClass('nospoilers').text($(this).text().replace('*',''));
});

$("button").click(function() {
 $("a").not('.nospoilers').hide();
});